# How to get the non-technical person test the iOS app under development?

Tags: ios, testing, mobile, project, project-management

In an Agile based, client involved iOS project, how to get the client(non-technical) test the iOS app which is under constant iteration? Given the fact that Android can have apk files installed on the client's device for testing purpose(Correct me if I'm wrong, or if there is a better way for Android), iOS seems unable to do so. A developer certificate is not free and it allows only one Mac(the developer's Mac) to do the testing.

In my view, A non-technical client should only rely on a package file (like the apk in Android) to test the app. However, I cannot figure out a way to do so in iOS. Although I can use my device to demonstrate my work, I think it is vital that the client has the freedom to test on his device. Is there a good practice for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Developer Account would allow you to use TestFlight to invite beta testers to download your app even before it is available in the app store.

Check out: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/ for more information.